# jQuery - read and unread items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `click` handler that changes the `icon` and adds an `active` class to the item.

The function works as intended except if the item proceeds a `read` item, it takes **two clicks to fire** instead of one.

Why isn't the status changing on first click?

```js
$(".activity__button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var icon = $(this).find("svg");
  var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
  if (status === "read") {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
    icon.attr("data-icon", "envelope");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .removeClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
  } else {
    $(this)
      .addClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
    icon.attr("data-icon", "envelope-open");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .addClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
  }
});
```

```css
.activity__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button svg {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--read svg {
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="activity__item activity__item--read">
    <div class="activity__button activity__button--read" data-status="read">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The last one is read (`data-status="read"`) but doesn't have the corresponding class, why is that? (before any Javascript)

Comment: instead of `.attr()` you should be using the `.data()` method of the data API. It is a bad practice of having dash separated CSS selectors like `activity__button--read`

Comment: check my answer bro it might help you bro !!!!

Comment: @Jeto, I updated the question code. The last item was intended to be marked as unread.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to check status and add/remove classes, just change your javascript code like this, it'll work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).on("click", '.activity__button', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('activity__button--read');
    if ($(this).hasClass('activity__button--read'))
        $(this).attr('data-status', 'read')
    else
        $(this).attr('data-status', 'unread')
 });
});
```

Rest all your code remains as is. Try this

Answer (score 0):

Because on the first click of the 4th element it will go into the first if statement. (Since you set data-status = "read")

You are missing the necessary class (activity__button--read) to visually show that the element is indeed has been read.

The script is actually triggered, you didn't see anything because it is removing nothing.

Comment: Sorry, the last item is meant to be unread. I have updated my question code

Answer (score 0):

Initial html class declaration was wrong in last element.That means missing class of  read `activity__item--read` and `activity__button--read` in last envelope. That why its open only on second click

1. For first click its added the class of to the element .Then second click applied the read status condition
2. First two element is `unread` .last two element are `read`
3. compare last two its a same status but missing read class in last one
4. Change the `status` or add the read class to parent

```js
$('.activity__button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
  if (status === "read") {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .removeClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
  } else {
    $(this)
      .addClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .addClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
  }
});
```

```css
.activity__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button .fas:before {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--read .fas:before {
  content: "\f2b6";
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="activity__item activity__item--read">
    <div class="activity__button activity__button--read" data-status="read">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item activity__item--read">
    <div class="activity__button activity__button--read" data-status="read">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, the last item is meant to be unread. I have updated my question code

Answer (score 0):

data status for the last item was "read" so we have to double click on it.i have changed it to "unread" and updated the js code too. please look at the code it works fine

```js
$('.activity__button').on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('activity__button--read ');
        $(this).attr('data-status', 'unread')
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('activity__item--read');
});

$('div[data-status="read"]').each(function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('activity__item--read');
})
$('div[data-status="unread"]').each(function(){ 
$(this).removeClass('activity__item--read');
})
```

```css
.activity__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button .fas:before {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--read .fas:before {
  content: "\f2b6";
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="activity__item activity__item--read">
    <div class="activity__button activity__button--read" data-status="read">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__item">
    <div class="activity__button" data-status="read">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.activity__item--read` isn't being added to the `.activity__item` when marked as read

Comment: @KyleUnderhill what is the problem is it not working fine?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. The last item was meant to be marked as unread. Also you will notice that unread items receive the class of `.activity__item--read`

Comment: @KyleUnderhill check the code right now bro . i have added a jquery method to add the class if it not present by load based on it data-status and its working fine.

Comment: .activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

Is still not happening

Comment: I will have to check as I update the questions code to incorporate Font Awesomes JS library, which turns icons into SVG's and requires the icon change to be handled through JS